# Count all pair of integers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find total count of such pairs of integers $X, Y$ such that $X*Y \leq N $

given that:

$X \leq A$
and
$Y \leq B$

$X, Y, A, B$  and  $N$ all are positive integers greater than $0$.

Ex:

if $A=2, B=2$ and  $N=3$
then $(1,1), (1,2), (2,1) $ total three pairs.

So, ans is $3$.

`

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Since you listed the tag "programming", why not write a program to compute the count?

Comment: I need an optimized way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For a programming solution you could use

$$\sum_{X=1}^{A}\min(\lfloor \frac{N}{X}\rfloor,B). $$

**Note**

$\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the integer part of $x$.